# Changing a column's values depending on another table's values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a column called `Status` in table `dbo.Dependencies` and columns `ReleaseId`, `TaskId` and `PhaseId` in table `dbo.DependencyList`. I have been trying to put together a code that will do the following: if the three columns that I enumerated from the second table are NULL, then `Status` should be 0 in the first table. If any of the columns is not null, then `Status` should become 1.

`DependencyList` also has a Foreign Key to `Dependencies` called `DependencyId`.

```
SELECT TaskId
    ,ReleaseId
    ,PhaseId
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (
                TaskId
                AND ReleaseId
                AND PhaseId
                ) IS NULL
            THEN UPDATE Dependencies SET STATUS = '0' WHERE Id = '3004'
        ELSE UPDATE Dependencies SET STATUS = '1' WHERE Id = '3004'
        END
FROM Dependencies
INNER JOIN DependencyList ON Dependencies.Id = DependencyList.DependencyId
WHERE Dependencies.Id = '3004'
```

That's the code that I came up with, with no success. The errors are as it follows:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

What is the correct way in which this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` while joining like this:

```
UPDATE dependencies
SET STATUS = CASE WHEN TaskId IS NULL AND ReleaseId IS NULL AND PhaseId IS NULL 
                  THEN '0' 
                  ELSE '1' 
             END
FROM Dependencies 
INNER JOIN DependencyList ON Dependencies.Id=DependencyList.DependencyId WHERE Dependencies.Id='3004'
```

Comment: Hey! What about *if the three columns that I enumerated from the second table are NULL, then Status should be 0*?! This solution does the opposite.

Comment: Good catch!  I flipped the flag values in the `CASE`.

Comment: It doesn't work too. If one of the three columns is not null then should be 1! Your solution works only in case when all three are not null.

Comment: *If any of the columns is not null, then Status should become 1*

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` in SQL Server is an expression, not a control flow statement. You could use a `CASE` as an expression to update `Status` like the example below.

```
UPDATE dbo.Dependencies
SET Status =
    CASE WHEN TaskId IS NULL AND ReleaseId IS NULL AND PhaseId IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END
WHERE Id='3004'
 AND Dependencies.Id IN(
SELECT DependencyList.DependencyId
FROM dbo.DependencyList
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE  T1
SET     T1.STATUS = CASE WHEN COALESCE(T2.TaskId, T2.ReleaseId, T2.PhaseId) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM    Dependencies T1
INNER JOIN DependencyList T2 ON T1.Id=T2.DependencyId
WHERE   T1.Id='3004'
```